# Why does strict typescript sometimes allow a mixture of fields across a union?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to understand the use case where typescript allows instances to pass union type type-checking when it doesn't pass any individual component. The example I'm looking at is using types

```js
type Bar = {
  bar: true
  bar2: number
}
type Baz = {
  baz: number
}
type Foo = Bar | Baz
```

which catches

```js
const bazArg: Baz = {baz: 5, bar: true}
```

as a type error, but does not catch

```js
const bazArg: Foo = {baz: 5, bar: true}
```

This allows bugs like

```js
const fn = (foo: Foo): number => 'bar' in foo ? foo.bar2 : foo.baz
const bazArg: Foo = {baz: 5, bar: true}
console.log(fn(bazArg)) // logs undefined
```

[typescriptland link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgJygXigbwFBSgI0QLimAQFcItdEAmQgOxIFscIEMBfDUSWOALxXQU8vOo2asOXaADEA9rIHwkAHx68MGAMazaAZ2BQAZrQEAKQ-MJzZASlFMWKAHxQA5HgSuoASxMWFAPxG8gB0HlRQhP5hfFo6+pS8AIIIAOZW8gJowoQArAA0lAiExGQc2nqyADYQIVWyqea0psIpqTY2UAD0XVD1qbpQJLQAJhCGvhAjGEA)

Comment: See the answer to the linked question.  TypeScript does not perform excess property checking on cross-member union fields (for non-discriminated unions).

Comment: It's annoying because this is incorrect for strict typescript
"Types in TypeScript are open in the sense that an object has to have at least the properties described by a type for it to match. So the object { value: 7, data: 'test', note: 'hello' } matches the type { value: number, data: string }, even though it has that excess note property. So your c variable is indeed a valid sth."

just try:
type T = { value: number, data: string }
const x: T = { value: 7, data: 'test', note: 'hello' }

Comment: see https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDeUBuBDANgVwgLigDtsBbAIwgCcAaKAE3WHQIGdhKBLQgcygF8AUAGMA9oTZQAHgTiIUGHPigB2WgyYEA5MAhtNtQiJ1aAFhEyYRm-gKA

Comment: The statement is correct, but I'm happy to edit if it's confusing or misleading.  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mM8xZN), you can indeed assign that object to that type.  But when you do so directly via an *object literal*, it prevents the assignment due to excess property checking... which is essentially a linter feature and not really a type safety issue.

Comment: Ah I see the distinction. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: I've edited the other answer to be a little more explicit, hope that helps